# How do I execute code when internet is back and app is on the background?

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile

I have a callback to be executed when the internet is back on the device and my app is in the background. I'm working with react-native-NetInfo and it does not send events in the background because it uses SCNetworkReachability. How is this possible? What should be used? Notifications?

Answer (score 2):

You can use background function in [react-native-notifications](https://wix.github.io/react-native-notifications/api/general-events#registernotificationreceivedforeground)

```js
Notifications.events().registerNotificationReceivedBackground((notification: Notification, completion: (response: NotificationCompletion) => void) => {
   NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
     if(state.isConnected) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(notification.payload));

       // Calling completion on iOS with `alert: true` will present the native iOS inApp notification.
       completion({alert: true, sound: true, badge: false});
     }
   });
    
});
```

If you need to continuously check the Internet connection part, you can solve the problem with the following library.

```js
import BackgroundFetch from "react-native-background-fetch";

useEffect(()=> {
  initBackgroundFetch();
},[])

const addEvent = (taskId) => {

    return NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
     if(state.isConnected) {
       // send notification
     }
   });
  }

const initBackgroundFetch = async () => {
    // BackgroundFetch event handler.
    const onEvent = async (taskId) => {
      console.log('[BackgroundFetch] task: ', taskId);
      // Do your background work...
      await addEvent(taskId);
      // IMPORTANT:  You must signal to the OS that your task is complete.
      BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
    }

    // Timeout callback is executed when your Task has exceeded its allowed running-time.
    // You must stop what you're doing immediately BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId)
    const onTimeout = async (taskId) => {
      console.warn('[BackgroundFetch] TIMEOUT task: ', taskId);
      BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
    }

    // Initialize BackgroundFetch only once when component mounts.
    let status = await BackgroundFetch.configure({minimumFetchInterval: 15}, onEvent, onTimeout);

    console.log('[BackgroundFetch] configure status: ', status);
  }
```

Comment: it sounds good, but how do I get the notification when the device's internet is back? This is what I need, know when the internet is back and execute a code.

Comment: @moigamijunior you can use `react-native-background-fetch`

Comment: @moigamijunior  my answer updated

Comment: I've looked about this package, but it does fetch every 15 minutes and it's too much time to wait for reconnection. Is there another way? Thanks!

Comment: @moigamijunior This is just an example, and the time depends on your setting.